# C# save System.Drawing.Graphics to .png

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.drawing.graphics

I tried with the graphics.Save();

```
Graphics newImage = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
newImage.DrawImage(bmp, 87, 37, 0, 0);
newImage.Save();
```

but when i try to set the file name like in the Image.Save(@"HereGoesName.PNG"); method i get an error saying "No overload for the method 'Save' takes 1 arguments)"

and everywhere i searched says to do the following

```
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(1024), Convert.ToInt32(1024), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
 bitmap.Save(@"HereGoesName.PNG", ImageFormat.Png);
```

From what i understand this is to create a graphics from a bitmap in here and i am trying to do the oposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `Save` on the bitmap, not the graphics:

```
Graphics newImage = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
newImage.DrawImage(bmp, 87, 37, 0, 0);
bmp2.Save("HereGoesName.PNG", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple: Your line `Graphics newImage = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);` creates a graphics object referring to `bmp2` image.

All drawing actions draw direct on your `bmp2` Bitmap

So you can simply save your modified image with:

```
bmp2.Save(@"foo.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```